# Apollo Client Full WebSocket Transport gives me the error this.networkInterface.query is not a function

Tags: javascript, apollo, apollo-client

I can make the hybrid approach work but I want to use the full websocket transport where every graphql operation is done over the socket. I did exactly like their [documentation](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws#full-websocket-transport).

```
import { SubscriptionClient } from 'subscriptions-transport-ws'
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

const client = new SubscriptionClient('ws://localhost:5000/graphql', { reconnect: true })
const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({ networkInterface: client })

apolloClient.query({
  query: gql`query { app }`
})
```

Gives me the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error: this.networkInterface.query is not a function
    at new ApolloError (ApolloError.js:34)
    at QueryManager.js:325
    at QueryManager.js:818
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at QueryManager.js:815
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at QueryManager.broadcastQueries (QueryManager.js:812)
    at QueryManager.js:281
    at <anonymous>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subscriptions-transport-ws has some breaking changes in 0.9.x version. You can install 0.8.3 or try to make the newer version work.